# Is the 8088 processor 8 bit or 16 bit?

Tags: size, cpu

In Randall Hyde's Art of Assembly it says the 8088 CPU was 8 bits whilst the 8086 was 16 bits solely because of the width of the data bus.

I have always thought that the address size determined the size of the CPU.

Please shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## From Wikipedia

> The 16-bit registers and the one megabyte address range were unchanged, however. In fact, according to the Intel documentation, the 8086 and 8088 have the same execution unit (EU)—only the bus interface unit (BIU) is different.

So the processor is functionally identical, but the memory bus is smaller.  The main purpose was for compatibility with 8-bit interfaces.  If a 16-bit interface was wanted, then it would take 2 CPU cycles to accomplish what the 8086 could do in one.

There was a greater availability of 8-bit chips at the time.

Comment: So was the chip 8 bit or 16 bit?

Comment: It's execution unit is **identical** to the 8086. The data-bus is 8 bit.  The chip is 16 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any official definition of the property "x-bit cpu", i suppose it does not exist.

I would say that "x-bit cpu" property indicates that the cpu can manipulate the data (inside the chip) with the size of "x-bits" at once. To be more specific  it has so called general registers with the size of "x"bits. So it can add (subtract, divide, multiply, xor etc) the data of "x-bits" length at once.

```
8086 has 16-bit general registers = 16-bit cpu 

8088 has 16-bit general registers = 16-bit cpu 

80510 has 32-bit general registers = 32-bit cpu
```

Again, the official definition of the property is unknown.

the wiki about [ia-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32)  says =

> The primary defining characteristic of IA-32 is the availability of
> 32-bit general-purpose processor registers (for example, EAX and EBX),
> 32-bit integer arithmetic and logical operations, 32-bit offsets
> within a segment in protected mode, and the translation of segmented
> addresses to 32-bit linear addresses.

I prefer to think that the bitnes of general registers is  enough to determine the x-bit cpu property.

The funny thing is intel itself defines cpu bitness by using different criteria from time to time. if you [look](https://www.ndr-nkc.de/download/datenbl/i8088.pdf) at the official intel doc it says

> 8088 is 8-bit hmos microprocessor

( i suppose they defined 8-bit cpu based on 8-bit data bus interface. remember this criteria). At the same time they say at the same document that the cpu has

> 16-bit internal architecture

Thats funny.. 8-bit cpu with 16-bit internal architecture.

Okey. Lets [look](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/intel/pentium/1995_Intel_Pentium_Processors_and_Related_Components.pdf) at another example Intel pentium 510.

They say it is

> 32-bit microprocessor

the cpu has 64-bit data bus, so based on previous example we would need to say that intel 510 is 64-bit cpu however it is wrong.

The conclusion - to determine cpu bitness look at the size of general registers.